# How to recreate bending from simple deform modifier, within geometry nodes?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, transforms

My goal is to recreate the simple deform modifier within geometry nodes. So far I got twisting, now I wanted to make bending.

On the right side of the image below is an object bent by 180 degrees through simple deform modifier. On the left is what I managed to create so far, with nodes in the next image.

[image: result and goal]

[image: geo nodes]

I'm guessing I need to use the offset input in the set position node to further adjust vertices, but I don't really know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a basic set up that does bending. It’s not a full solution because it only bends around the Y axis and only starts at zero on the Z axis. But I think it demonstrates one way to achieve bending in geometry nodes.
[image: basic geometry nodes bend setup]

[image]